python os module does not rename the file, even if the file exists - os.rename(src, dst)
I am trying to rename files from a directory. But for some reason which I do not know, the files are not getting renamed.
Code:

def extract_info_from_filename(file_name):
    parts = file_name.split('Z')
    part1 = parts[0]
    part2 = parts[1]
    
    return part1, part2

def find_csv_files_to_rename(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        if 'rename' in root:
            for file_name in files:
                if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
                    original_file_path = root + '/' + file_name
                    print(f"File Name: {file_name}, Extracted Info: {extract_info_from_filename(file_name)}")
                    extracted_parts = extract_info_from_filename(file_name)
                    new_file_name = f"{extracted_parts[0]}Z_treatment{extracted_parts[1]}"
                    print(f"New File name: {new_file_name}")
                    #new_file_path = os.path.join(root,new_file_name)
                    new_file_path =root+'/'+new_file_name
                    print(f"New File Path Exists: {os.path.exists(new_file_path)}")
                    print(f"Original File Path Exists: {os.path.exists(original_file_path)}")
                    print(f"Root: {root}")
                    print(f"New file path: {new_file_path}")
                    if not os.path.exists(new_file_path):        
                        os.rename(original_file_path, new_file_path)
                        if os.rename(original_file_path, new_file_path):
                            print(f'Renamed: {file_name} -> {new_file_name} \n')
                    else:
                        print(f'File already exists: {original_file_path} \n')


root_directory = 'input_files'
find_csv_files_to_rename(root_directory)

Output is:
File Name: 2023-07-08T00_28_04_750Z_Aachen_01.01.2022-P06.2023.csv, Extracted Info: ('2023-07-08T00_28_04_750', '_Aachen_01.01.2022-P06.2023.csv')
New File name: 2023-07-08T00_28_04_750Z_treatment_Aachen_01.01.2022-P06.2023.csv
New File Path Exists: False
Original File Path Exists: False
Root: input_files\rename_and_validate\XXXX\year=2023\month=07\day=08\XXXX
New file path: input_files\rename_and_validate\XXXX\year=2023\month=07\day=08\XXXX/2023-07-08T00_28_04_750Z_treatment_Aachen_01.01.2022-P06.2023.csv

Error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'input_files\\rename_and_validate\\XXXX\\year=2023\\month=07\\day=08\\XXXX/2023-07-08T00_28_04_750Z_Aachen_01.01.2022-P06.2023.csv' -> 'input_files\\rename_and_validate\\XXXX\\year=2023\\month=07\\day=08\\XXXX/2023-07-08T00_28_04_750Z_treatment_Aachen_01.01.2022-P06.2023.csv'

I kindly want to know the solution. I have tried all possible way of addressing the issue, from the modifying the paths (using .join function). But seems like the same issue.

you have the line os.rename(original_file_path, new_file_path) twice. Once alone, once in your if. After the first rename, the second must fail because the file is already renamed. Try removing the standalone line

I did that. Still the same issue.

Quite curious, it something to do with filename and the size of the name?

Is XXXX in the path literal or is it something longer?

I would not say really Long. But something like = 'Folder name extra 2 or 3 words'

Answer was incorrect. Author found another solution The issue is resolved: It was about enabling LongPath in my windows through regedit

File Name: 2023-07-08T00_28_04_750Z_Aachen_01.01.2022-P06.2023.csv, Extracted Info: ('2023-07-08T00_28_04_750', '_Aachen_01.01.2022-P06.2023.csv')
New File name: 2023-07-08T00_28_04_750Z_treatment_Aachen_01.01.2022-P06.2023.csv
New File Path Exists: False
Original File Path Exists: False
This is the output I receive based on your code. Could there be more scenarios why it fails? Technically it should work.

Please provide full log including                     print(f"Root: {root}")
print(f"New file path: {new_file_path}")

The issue is resolved: It was about enabling LongPath in my windows through regedit

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
